# Array about Uncaught TypeError in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This a part of my code.

But in the console appeared:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I don't know why `alert(data[index].title);` doesn't appear.

So, how can I do it?

```
var data = [];

    var api = function () {

        clear_overlays();

        var url = 'http://tw.tranews.com/map/dStores.asp?x1=' + bounds.x1 + '&x2=' + bounds.x2 + '&y1=' + bounds.y1 + '&y2=' + bounds.y2;

            $.get('proxy.php', {url: url}, function (resp) {

            var near = $('.near');
            near.empty();

            var xml = $(resp); 
                var data = xml.find('m');

            $.map(data, function (obj, i) {
                var m = $(obj);
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(m.find('vLat').text(), m.find('vLng').text());
                var title = m.find('vName').text();

                        var markerOptions = {
                            map: map,
                            position: latlng,
                            title: title
                        };
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                        markers.push(marker);
                        marker.setMap(map);


                        var store = {
                          image: m.find('vImg1').text(),
                          title: m.find('vName').text()

                        };
                        data.push(store);

                        var image = m.find('vImg1').text();                         
                        var html = '<div class="perview"><a href="#"><img src="'+image+'" width="50" height="50" alt="'+title+'" /></a></div>'; 
                        $(html).appendTo(near);                         
            }); 
                $('.perview').on("click", "img", function(){
                    var index = $('.preview img').index(this);

                      alert(data[index].title);
                /*var msg = '<div class="preview">' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</div>';
                    $('.info_content').animate({opacity: 1}, 300, function () {                         
                        $('.info').hide().empty().append(msg).delay(300).fadeIn(500);
                    });*/
                });
            }, 'XML');
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.perview').on("click", "img", function(){
     var index = $('.preview img').index(this);
```

probably is the problem, because `perview` is not `preview`. If an element is not in the set, `.index` returns `-1`, which doesn't work as an index for the array. I don't know your markup but you should probably rename the one or the other.